# How to store a value that can be read from every URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies, global

How can I store a value that can be read from every URL using javascript? I need somthing, that can act as global storage for browser. I have tries cookies and localstorage, but they have domain restriction while reading.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *global storage*. What you can do is to store your information on your server and let other sites request it.

Comment: available stored data is supposed to be a accessible only to the domain that stored them. I am not sure why someone would like to expose their cookies to everyone...

Comment: if every domain needs to access a variable value from the browser, it seems like it is like a `setting` for the browser. Otherwise, javascript cannot do much when it comes to cross-domain variables.

Comment: _"need somthing, that can act as global storage for browser"_ What is application ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should explain **why**? What ever it is you are trying to achieve may have a different solution SO people can recommend.

Anyway, here are a couple of options (there are most likely more):

- Store the data in a server, and have clients request it
- Create a browser extension. This should allow you to store things globally depending on the browser. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted for example